# Improving Chaos Game efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've written this script to use the turtle module to replicate the Chaos Game I saw on Numberphile's channel. There are a large amount of dots being drawn to actually make it work well in a larger scale. I assume the large amount of dots is what causes the program to begin running slower after a bit and I was wondering if anyone could help me come up with a workaround for this.

I'm open for any kind of solution, as long as the controls remain the same and the number of vertexes can be any number above 3.

If someone doesn't know what the Chaos Game is, it's a game where you have polygon with any amount of vertexes. At first you place a dot inside the polygon, randomly choose one of the vertexes and draw a new dot halfway in-between the dot you just placed earlier and the randomly chosen vertex. You keep repeating this process and each time you'll use the newly drawn dot.

In this script I've also included a rule to make sure it doesn't choose the same vertex two times in a row to form nice fractals with more than 3 vertexes. 3 vertexes actually forms the Sierpinski triangle.

Here's a link to Numberphile's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs

As you can probably tell, I'm somewhat new to Python and coding in general.

Full code:

```
import turtle as t
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint
wn = t.Screen()
wn.colormode(255)
t.pu();t.ht();t.speed(0)
plist = []

l = 0
val = 0

pb=ttk.Progressbar(orient="horizontal",length=wn.window_width(),mode="determinate")
pb.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
pb["value"]=0

def Clear():
    t.clear()
    plist = []
def Dot(x, y):
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.dot(5, (0, 0, 255))
    plist.append(t.pos())
def Run(x, y):
    wn.onscreenclick(None)
    wn.tracer(0, 0)
    l = len(plist)
    pb["maximum"]=l*1000
    xyc = randint(0, l-1)
    xyc_old = 0
    for _ in range(l*10):
        xyc = randint(0, l-1)
        for i in range(100):
            xyc = randint(0, l-1);
            if l >= 4:
                while xyc == xyc_old:
                    xyc = randint(0, l-1);
                xyc_old = xyc;
            t.goto((t.pos()[0]+plist[xyc][0])/2, (t.pos()[1]+plist[xyc][1])/2);     
            t.dot(2, (255, 0, 0));
            pb["value"]+=1;
            pb.update()
        wn.update()
    plist.clear()
    wn.onscreenclick(Dot, btn=1)
    wn.onscreenclick(Run, btn=3)  
wn.onscreenclick(Dot, btn=1)
wn.onscreenclick(Run, btn=3)
wn.onkey(Clear, "c")
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I feel like my coding style is very different from a lot of the people on here, but I hope that isn't an issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume the large amount of dots is what causes the program to begin
>   running slower after a bit and I was wondering if anyone could help me
>   come up with a workaround for this.

Surprisingly, no.  It's your own instrumentation (progress bar) slowing you down. Comment out:

```
pb.update()
```

and watch what happens.

> I feel like my coding style is very different from a lot of the people
>   on here, but I hope that isn't an issue.

It's an issue where it overlaps with *bad* coding style.  E.g. lack of white space, use of semicolons, effective no-ops in the code, etc.  My rework of your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randrange

def clear():
    turtle.clear()
    plist.clear()

def dot(x, y):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.dot(5, 'blue')
    plist.append(turtle.position())

def run(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None, btn=1)
    screen.onscreenclick(None, btn=3)
    screen.onkey(None, 'c')

    length = len(plist)
    flag = length >= 4
    pb['maximum'] = length * 1000
    xyc_old = 0

    for _ in range(length * 100):
        for _ in range(10):
            xyc = randrange(length)

            if flag:
                while xyc == xyc_old:
                    xyc = randrange(length)
                xyc_old = xyc

            x, y = turtle.position()
            dx, dy = plist[xyc]
            turtle.goto((x + dx) / 2, (y + dy) / 2)
            turtle.dot(2)

        pb['value'] += 10
        pb.update()

    plist.clear()
    pb['value'] = 0

    screen.onscreenclick(dot, btn=1)
    screen.onscreenclick(run, btn=3)
    screen.onkey(clear, 'c')

plist = []

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setundobuffer(None)
turtle.color('red')
turtle.penup()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(orient='horizontal', length=screen.window_width(), mode='determinate')
pb.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
pb['value'] = 0

screen.onscreenclick(dot, btn=1)
screen.onscreenclick(run, btn=3)
screen.onkey(clear, 'c')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Other changes include:

The `plist = []` in `Clear()` won't work without a `global plist`.  Use `plist.clear()` instead.

You also need to disable (and reenable) `wn.onkey(Clear, "c")` during `Run` otherwise your user can break the program.  You also need to disable the two mouse buttons independently.

You really want `randrange()`, not `randint()`.

Comment: Hmm, I'd just added the progress bar the day I posted this question. There had been similar performance issues before, but somehow this already seems far faster.

I wonder if it could be the randrange doing most of the work here? I believe those semicolons were left there from when I experimented this script with using exec() to execute the block that actually does the drawing.